# Migration Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We have converted Oracle database to SQL Server. We are facing an issue with null vs blank.

Scenario:

In Oracle:

```
Create table Student 
(
      Sno int, 
      FName varchar(20) not null, 
      MName varchar(30) null,
      Lname varchar(20) not null
)

Insert into Student (Sno, Fname, Mname, Lname) 
values (10, 'James' , '', 'Clark')
```

Record is inserted into Oracle with `MName` being stored as null, even if we pass a blank string (`''`) as value.

```
10,James,null,Clark
```

However, the row being inserted into SQL Server has `MName` stored as blank string, showing empty space in the table, even we have the default constraint.

```
10,James,,Clark
```

We want to handle blank strings (`''`) being inserted into SQL Server table as `null`  which is the similar behavior of Oracle database.

Comment: How are you constructing those insert statements?

Comment: It would be best to change the insert queries but you could create a trigger on the table to update zero-length string values to `NULL`. The trigger approach is probably the easiest way to simulate the non-ANSI SQL Oracle behavior in SQL Server.

Comment: @Dan Guzman : I maybe wrong, but I'm a bit surprised at the  suggestion to use a Trigger in this case. They are planning to migrate a whole database and I think the OP's concern might not just be with a single column in this table, which could mean using several triggers? Wouldn't it be advisable to tackle this problem in their migration tool/script which puts  blank string for null columns, while retrieving from Oracle?

Comment: @KaushikNayak, my understanding is the migration to SQL Server has already been done. The problem is with the application `INSERT` queries that specify an empty string to store a `NULL` values. The trigger method would avoid changing the app code but only as a workaround until the app code can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to use the `NULLIF()` function. In your example INSERT statement you'd way to say

```
Insert into Student(Sno,Fname,Mname,Lname)
  values (@varSno,@varFname ,NULLIF(@varMname, ''),@varLname)
```

In an UPDATE it might be used like

```
UPDATE STUDENT
  SET Fname = @varFname,
      Mname = NULLIF(@varMname, ''),
      Lname = @varLname
  WHERE Sno = @varSno
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Note that this will also change strings that contain all spaces to NULL, not just empty strings.